# Progress Bar via Python CGI

Tags: python, html, progress-bar, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import sys
import os
for i in range(10):
    progress_bar = \
        """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Display a gauge:</p>
        <meter value="%s" min="0" max="10">2 out of 10</meter><br>
        </body>
        </html>
        """%(i)

    print  progress_bar
    sys.stdout.flush() # do this after the print
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Here I am attempting to create a progress bar where 'i' is the progress indicator. [image]. The screen shot is given below. What I expected is that by using sys.stdout.flush() the previous HTML prints are eliminated, retaining only the current progress of 'i', but it does not work. Any ideas how to reach my objective?

Comment: These things are done via javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Your Python script is producing a HTML file which is ultimately read by the browser. If you click "View source" in your browser, you should see the same thing that you would see if you run your Python script in the console.

This should make it clear why one print statement doesn't "overwrite" another. As far as the browser's concerned, it's reading static content, just like it would be if you simply put a HTML file on your web server. The only difference is that using Python you can generate that HTML file however you like.

To make a progress bar that shows as dynamic in the browser, you will need to use client-side scripting (Javascript).

If the process you want to indicate progress for is server-side (Python), the basic approach could go like this:

- Make a Python script which serves some information (in JSON, pure text, or anything else that's convenient for you) which indicates the progress of the operation, e.g: a JSON document like `{"finished": false, "progress": 54.9, "target": 100.0}`
- Make a Javascript function which sets the visual state your progress bar based on a number.
- Make a Javascript function which performs a request to the URL of your Python-side progress-serving script and parses the information returned.
- Connect these pieces together. While the operation is ongoing, periodically poll the server for its progress and set the progress bar accordingly.

If you *actually* know (or can guess, without being at all worried about the indicator reflecting reality) that the operation will take a fixed amount of time, you can skip a lot of this by simply making the Javascript progress indicator dependent on the time instead of on the actual state of the operations that are going on.